# FabricJS FlipX object

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am having trouble flipping or mirroring the object horizontally when the object itself is clicked on the FabricJS canvas.

I came close but it was mirroring the object when it was being resized too, which I didn't want.

I would guess I need to add the 'flipX: true' attribute to object on the first click and on the next click remove that attribute and so on with each click. Or maybe that is over complicating it and it can be done much easier with a flipX function I do not know.

I did find a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/E4Vcr/) that flipped the object, but it was onclick of a button not the object itself.

I am struggling to solve this :\

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eA3xH/122/)

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

canvas.on('object:selected', function() {
  toggle('flipX');
});

// create a rectangle
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  angle: 20,
  fill: 'red'
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could accomplish that in the following way ...

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// mouse event
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
    if (e.target) {
        if (!e.target.__corner) {
            e.target.toggle('flipX');
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
        e.target.__corner = null;
    }
});

// create a rectangle
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    angle: 20,
});

// set gradient (for demonstration)
rect.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: -rect.width / 2,
    y1: 0,
    x2: rect.width / 2,
    y2: 0,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#ffe47b',
        1: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
    }
});

canvas.add(rect);
rect.set('flipX', true);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="208" height="208"></canvas>
```

Comment: For some reason the code snippet isn't working, but I tested the code elsewhere and that is exactly what I am trying to achieve :) thanks! It works different to how I expected, without the gradient I wouldn't have been able to see the flip. I thought adding an angle was enough and the angel would reverse, therefore displaying the flip. Maybe this is why I was finding it so difficult to get to work as my demo wasn't sufficient.

Comment: How could I adjust this so when clicking and dragging the object it doesn't FlipX? Currently if you click to move the object it will flip, so you need to click it again once moved to flip it back. I didn't mention it at first because I thought I could work that part on my own at least! But no success so far!

Answer (score 1):

Same from above, different case.

Apply flip to background image

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('../' +ImageUrl, function (img02) {
                    
                    Backcanvas.setBackgroundImage(img02, Backcanvas.renderAll.bind(Backcanvas), {
                        backgroundImageStretch: false,
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        originX: 'left',
                        originY: 'top',
                        flipY:'true'
                    });

                    Backcanvas.renderAll();
                    Backcanvas.backgroundImage.setCoords();    


                    canvas.renderAll();
                    Backcanvas.renderAll();


                }, { crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
```